# how to reindex elasticsearch data after fixed time of interval using grails?

Tags: grails, elasticsearch

i have installed elasticsearch plugin in my grails project and now i want that whenever i build my application on production elasticSearch data should get reindexed automatically . .Is there a way to do this.??

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://noamt.github.io/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/guide/indexing.html) you should be able re-index everything from your `grails-app/conf/BootStrap.groovy` when your application starts.

For example, something like this:

```
// grails-app/conf/BootStrap.groovy
class BootStrap {    
    def elasticSearchService

    def init = { servletContext ->
        environments {
          production {
            // Index all searchable instances
            elasticSearchService.index()
          }
        }
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

The same concept of re-indexing would apply if you wanted to setup a Quartz job which ran on a schedule as well. However, I will leave that for you to implement.

Comment: Is there any other way to use elasticsearch in grails without installing elasticsearch plugin .?? it seems not the good idea as searchable data will be displayed after reindexing again n again..

Comment: That would be a different question, since this original question was about using the elasticsearch plugin. However, since Grails is a Spring/Java application there is nothing stopping you from using Elasticsearch purely from a Java perspective. So, no, you don't NEED the plugin.